Buildfire - User Import via CSV file fails with encrypted base64 password?
BuildFire doesn't have seem to have any explicit documentation on bulk-import of users via a CSV file, except to "use the import template"
We are attempting to bulk-upload users from another integrated system with the other system's password encrypted in base64 and the passwordHashType field as "base64"  Our first test is to update an existing user, so the Override Existing User field is marked "Yes".
Every attempt to import this single-line file comes back with the response "Imported with Errors" and the returned error file only contains a nondescript error, "Invalid Login".
Can anyone point me to some specific documentation on BuildFire User Importing procedures?  There doesn't appear to be any content in BuildFire University on this topic.  I haven't even found any documentation on what values for passwordHashType might actually be valid.
